# python json dumps not converting from text/html

Tags: python, json

Can somebody please explain why its not converting to `json` from `text` and what I require to get that done and how to get it accomplished.

```
>>> import json
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://localhost:8000/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
>>> r.headers.get('content-type')
'text/html'
>>>
```

**Update:**

With the header accept as application/json lead me to No JSON object could be decoded. Please help..

```
>>> import json
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://localhost:8000/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','accept':'application/json'}  
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
>>> r.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'date': 'Thu, 13 Jun 2013 01:43:16 GMT', 'content-type':         'text/html', 'server': 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3'})
>>> r.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py",      line 651, in json
return json.loads(self.text or self.content, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>>
```

Comment: Your request is being sent as json, but the response is HTML. It's up to the server running on `localhost:8000` to set the content type for the response, so it will depend on what that server is.

Comment: @Aya Can you tell me how to set the content type to json in my server `localhost:8000`

Comment: Well, I'd need to see some of the code for the server.

Comment: Based on your response, it appears the server is returning HTML. One thing you may want to check is that the page is returning a successful response code (something in the 200s). I've seen cases where an error page is returned as HTML even when the content requested was something else.

Answer (score 2):

You are only stating that the content type of your request is `application/json`. You can try requesting json using an [accept-header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1):

```
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
```

but if the server ignores the header it won't help you.

Also it is possible that the response content actually is json, so `r.json()` might work, and it's only the content-type header that is misleading.